# How to shorten the expiration time on Firebase auth tokens for testing

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to test my refresh token logic using Firebase auth but waiting an hour for it to expire is maddening. The documentation doesn't seem to mention anything about customizing the time: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

I am signing in with:

```
firebase
      .doSignInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

Ideally I would like it to expire in five minutes or less. Anyone know how to do this?

FWIW: I found this discussion (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/NWKw28SvBi8/fi4s2l1rAgAJ) which makes it sound like it wasn't possible over a year ago, just hoping this has changed or someone has found a workaround since then.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to change the expiration time for ID/access tokens minted by Firebase Authentication itself. The only thing I can think of is minting your own tokens, and setting the `exp` property to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm just manually testing the code. I don't want to create custom tokens just for that. Frustrating that there isn't a better way!

Answer (score 0):

You can actually revoke tokens based on your own preferences in Firebase Admin SDK though it depends on your use-case ofcourse.